# Copy cut paste iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

I have a UIWebView. In this, i want to catch when the user use the copy menu in order to copy selection into a pasteboard.

Afterwards when the user touch a button, the content will be paste in a mail.

I want to intercept when the user click on copy or cut menu. so i had this two methods :

```
- (void)cut:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"cuuuuuuuuuut");
}


- (void)copy:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"copyyy");
}
```

when i click on the cut menu, NSlog print cuuuuuuuuuut
but when i click on the copy menu , NSLog print nothing (copy method isn't called).

why ?

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest UIPasteboard in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html)? (Developer membership required)

Comment: Unless you just want to do your own methods, but UIPasteboard comes with the nice Apple looks already.